# Attempting to use a disconnected port in Chrome Native Messaging

Tags: javascript, linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a Hello World app for Chrome Native Messaging. I've created a Chrome extension, a binary executable and html page. I'm on Linux and using Chromium.

I think I've registered everything properly, however, it still isn't working.

From my web page I send a message to my extension, and here's a part of code of my extention:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, snd, sndResp) {    
  var prt = chrome.runtime.connectNative('com.example.my_app');
  prt.postMessage(msg); // Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port
```

Note that the "msg" isn't empty and has the same content in it as one that I put into it on the html page. So there's no issue about that.

However, in the extension the error is:

```
Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port
```

Comment: Have you included host manifest file at `~/.config/chromium/NativeMessagingHosts/` ?

Comment: @guest271314, yes. can it have any file name or strictly com.example.my_app.json?

Comment: You should be able to use any file name. See also _"[runtime.sendNativeMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendNativeMessage) can be used to send a message to native application without creating a port"_ , https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging/app/

Comment: Have you read https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging?

Comment: @guest271314, yes.

Comment: Did the error occur using the sample pattern linked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604284/attempting-to-use-a-disconnected-port-in-chrome-native-messaging#comment62693695_37604284 ?

Comment: @guest271314, I don't know how much mine example and that one similar. I've copied the manifest to ~/.config/chromium/NativeMessagingHosts/ under the name "my_company....", so everything seems it's been set up properly. By the way, the name of the file can be random, right? what there were 2 different manifest files there but the same application name in them, how would chromimum know which file or app to choose?

Comment: @guest271314, what does the error imply, any guess?

Answer (score 1):

The error may caused when a connection get closed. It may failed because the tab is no longer active to receive the message.

Try to use [`runtime.connect`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-connect) or [`tabs.connect`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-connect) respectively. It allows you to distinguish between different types of connections.

When establishing a connection, each end is given a [`runtime.Port`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-Port) object which is used for sending and receiving messages through that connection.

Here is how you open a channel from a content script, and send and listen for messages:

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "knockknock"});
port.postMessage({joke: "Knock knock"});
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
if (msg.question == "Who's there?")
port.postMessage({answer: "Madame"});
else if (msg.question == "Madame who?")
port.postMessage({answer: "Madame... Bovary"});
});
```

Comment: why is that "connect" and not "connectNative"?

Comment: also, this `chrome.runtime.connectNative('com.example.my_app');` and this `chrome.runtime.connectNative('fdsfdsfdsfds');` behave the same way -- no error and the port.name is empty. why? I think Chromium can't find the native app at all.